# vim do not save buffer history after closing

Tags: vim, buffer

What setting should I add to my `.vimrc` file so that no information about previous open buffers is saved to `.viminfo`? I do want to save command history though.

By not preserving buffer history I mean when I open a fresh vim instance and I do **Ctrl+o** or **Ctrl+i** to not show buffers that were open in a previous session, but only buffers that were opened during the current session.

Thanks

Comment: Did you even read `:help 'viminfo'`?

Comment: I think that 90% of the questions on stack overflow could be avoided by reading the documentation. The problem is most of the times the documentation is too verbose or ambiguous. Yes I did read it and I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: Agreed. I actually find the very existence of this site to be a disgrace. That said, the doc explains what to do very clearly. So… either you didn't read `:help 'viminfo'` or Vim is not for you. But I'll give you the benefit of the doubt… If there's something in `:help 'viminfo'` that you didn't understand, explain to us what you understood, what you tried, what failed, what you didn't understood and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your `.vimrc`:

```sh
autocmd VimEnter *
        \ execute "
        \ let i = 0     | 
        \ while i < 100 | 
        \ mark '        | 
        \ let i = i + 1 | 
        \ endwhile      | 
        \ unlet i       |
        \ delm A-Z0-9"
```

This will wipe out the jump list for every session and delete marks.